# Вывести предложение определенное количество раз

Tags: c++

Помощь с маленькой программой

Как написать программу, в ее коде уже должно быть предложение (любой текст) и задать сколько раз это предложение программа должна повторить (тоже уже в коде).

Comment: @nichego_sebe, попробуйте разобраться (почитайте, скажем, K&R)

     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
      
     int 
     main (int ac, char *av[]) 
     {
        int rc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; !rc && i < atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "1"); i++)
          rc = puts("это любой текст") == EOF;
        return rc;
     }

что тут для чего.

Comment: @nichego_sebe, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Две переменных - целую и строковую.
Просишь написать повторяемое предложение.
Запоминаешь.
Спрашиваешь, сколько раз выводить?
Запоминаешь.
Пока текущий счетчик меньше ответа на второй вопрос - выводишь предложение.

ЗЫ Можно сделать проверку ввода числа.